# How to change "-" for "/"?

Tags: php, laravel

I have categories where i display icons based on category name.Problem is that i have category name with `2015/2016` but i cant put name of icon `2015/2016.png` so how can i find "-" and change it with "/" ? Any suggestion?

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle sidebarColor" data-toggle="dropdown"><img class="icon" src="assetsfront/img/icon/{{ $category->name }}.png" />{{ $category->name }} <span class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></span></a>
```

Comment: `str_replace()`? That is `str_replace('/', '-', $str);` You need to be clearer where to replace the string though (code looks like Blade/Laravel, so maybe you will want to change it in the model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my comment:

```
$img = str_replace('/', '-', $category->name);
// maybe in the model and then pass it to the view
```

And then later in the View:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle sidebarColor" data-toggle="dropdown"><img class="icon" src="assetsfront/img/icon/{{ $img }}.png" />{{ $category->name }} <span class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `str_ireplace()` for this

```
str_ireplace("/","-",$variable);
```

But make sure you have that file(`.png` with `-`) in your folder `assetsfront/img/icon/`.

Comment: where to put this str_replace?

Comment: Why str_ireplace and not str_replace as Jan said? Not many case insensitive searchs needed for "/"...

Comment: `$category->name` to `str_ireplace("/","-",$category->name)`

Comment: @Amarnasan normally i use `str_ireplace()`, coz sometimes, case matters(which will eat time unknowingly), so i added it..